# How to handle NULL Value in BigQuery while writing through Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am ingesting data from one Database to BigQuery using the `JdbcIO` Source connector and `BigQueryIO` Sink connector provided by `Apache Beam`.

Below is my sample table data:

[image]

As we can see few columns such as `id`, and `booking_date` contain NULL Value. So when I try to write data into BigQuery, it gives the below error

```
"message": "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Only optional fields can be set to NULL. Field: status; Value: NULL
```

if I pass `null` in `booking_date` it gives an `invalid date format error`.

Below is the RowMapper I am using to convert `JdbcIO` resultset into `TableRow`. it is the same code that  **GCP** `JdbcToBigQuery` Template is using.

```
public TableRow mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
  ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
  TableRow outputTableRow = new TableRow();
  for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    if (resultSet.getObject(i) == null) {
      outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), resultSet.getObject(i));
    // outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject(i)));
      continue;
    }

/*
 * DATE:      EPOCH MILLISECONDS -> yyyy-MM-dd
 * DATETIME:  EPOCH MILLISECONDS -> yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS
 * TIMESTAMP: EPOCH MILLISECONDS -> yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX
 *
 * MySQL drivers have ColumnTypeName in all caps and postgres in small case
 */
switch (metaData.getColumnTypeName(i).toLowerCase()) {
  case "date":
    outputTableRow.set(
        getColumnRef(metaData, i), dateFormatter.format(resultSet.getDate(i)));
    break;
  case "datetime":
    outputTableRow.set(
        getColumnRef(metaData, i),
        datetimeFormatter.format((TemporalAccessor) resultSet.getObject(i)));
    break;
  case "timestamp":
    outputTableRow.set(
        getColumnRef(metaData, i), timestampFormatter.format(resultSet.getTimestamp(i)));
    break;
  case "clob":
    Clob clobObject = resultSet.getClob(i);
    if (clobObject.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      LOG.warn(
          "The Clob value size {} in column {} exceeds 2GB and will be truncated.",
          clobObject.length(),
          getColumnRef(metaData, i));
    }
    outputTableRow.set(
        getColumnRef(metaData, i), clobObject.getSubString(1, (int) clobObject.length()));
    break;
  default:
        outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), resultSet.getObject(i).toString());
    }
  }

  return outputTableRow;
}
```

Click here for more details [JdbcToBigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/8e0c1bbf0f331a4043acac284076ff21a606ce1c/v2/googlecloud-to-googlecloud/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/utils/JdbcConverters.java#L18)

**Solution I tried but did not get success**

- I tried to skip that particular column when it is `null` then it gives the error `Missing required field`
- I tried to hard code value for all cases as "null" so that I can handle this particular value later but it gives the error `Could not convert value 'string_value: \t \"null\"' to integer`

**How can I handle all Null case?** Please note, I will not be able to ignore these rows since few columns contain values.

Comment: Either you'll have to filter out the problematic rows, or alter the schema for your BigQuery table to accept null values for the fields in question. BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, you have to pass `null` if the date value is `null` and you have to set the associated `BigQuery` columns to `NULLABLE` :

```java
public TableRow mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
  ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
  TableRow outputTableRow = new TableRow();
  for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    if (resultSet.getObject(i) == null) {
      outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), resultSet.getObject(i));
    // outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject(i)));
      continue;
    }

/*
 * DATE:      EPOCH MILLISECONDS -> yyyy-MM-dd
 * DATETIME:  EPOCH MILLISECONDS -> yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS
 * TIMESTAMP: EPOCH MILLISECONDS -> yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX
 *
 * MySQL drivers have ColumnTypeName in all caps and postgres in small case
 */
public void yourMethod() {
    switch (metaData.getColumnTypeName(i).toLowerCase()) {
        case "date":
            String date = Optional.ofNullable(resultSet.getDate(i))
                    .map(d -> dateFormatter.format(d))
                    .orElse(null);
            
            outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), date);
            break;
        case "datetime":
            String datetime = Optional.ofNullable(resultSet.getObject(i))
                    .map(d -> datetimeFormatter.format((TemporalAccessor) d))
                    .orElse(null);
            
            outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), datetime);
            break;
        case "timestamp":
            String timestamp = Optional.ofNullable(resultSet.getTimestamp(i))
                    .map(t -> timestampFormatter.format(t))
                    .orElse(null);
            
            outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), timestamp);
            break;
        case "clob":
            Clob clobObject = resultSet.getClob(i);
            if (clobObject.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                LOG.warn(
                        "The Clob value size {} in column {} exceeds 2GB and will be truncated.",
                        clobObject.length(),
                        getColumnRef(metaData, i));
            }
            outputTableRow.set(
                    getColumnRef(metaData, i), clobObject.getSubString(1, (int) clobObject.length()));
            break;
        default:
            outputTableRow.set(getColumnRef(metaData, i), resultSet.getObject(i).toString());
    }
    return outputTableRow;
}
```

For the `date`, `datetime` and timestamp blocs, I applied the transformation only if the value is not null, otherwise I retrieved default null value.

Comment: Thank you so much, so you have solved one of my critical issues w.r.t to Dataflow.